A question on Riesz representation theorem for Hilbert space.
Let $\ell^2$ be the space of real sequences that are square summable, i.e.
$$\ell^2=\left\{(x_n):x_n\in\mathbb{R},\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n^2<+\infty\right\}$$
Denoted by $(\cdot,\cdot)$ the usual $\ell^2$ inner product, then it's well known that $(\ell^2,(\cdot,\cdot))$ is a Hilbert space. Let
$$H_0=\left\{(x_n)\in\ell^2:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x_n^2<+\infty\right\}$$
by Fatou's lemma it's easy to see that $H_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^2,$ thus $(H_0,(\cdot,\cdot))$ is also a Hilbert space. The Riesz representation theorem states that there is a continuous isomorphism between $\ell^2$ and $(\ell^2)^\ast,$ say $T_1,$ and a continuous isomorphism between $H_0$ and $H_0^\ast,$ say $T_2.$ Moreover, since $H_0$ is a subspace of $\ell^2,$ we have a bounded linear map $R:(\ell^2)^{\ast}\to H_0^\ast,$ which maps each $f\in (\ell^2)^{\ast}$ to the restriction of $f$ on $H_0,$ namely $f\big{|}_{H_0}.$
Now here comes the problem: Take $(x_n)=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\in \ell^2,$ we have $R\circ T_1 (x_n)\in H_0^\ast,$ so since $T_2$ is surjective, there must be some $(y_n)\in H_0$ such that $T_2(y_n)=R\circ T_1(x_n).$ But that means
$$\left\langle T_2(y_n),(z_n)\right\rangle = \left\langle R\circ T_1(x_n),(z_n)\right\rangle,\qquad\forall (z_n)\in H_0,$$
where $\left\langle\cdot,\cdot\right\rangle $ is the pairing between $H_0^\ast$ and $H_0.$ Unpack the definition of $T_1,T_2,R,$ the above equality is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_nz_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}z_n.$ If we take $(z_n)=(\delta_{kn})\in H_0,$ with $\delta_{kn}$ the Kronecker symbol and $k\in \mathbb{N}^+,$ we derive $y_k=\frac{1}{k},$ which contradicts to the restriction that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2y_k^2<+\infty$!
It seems to me that all the arguments above are reasonable, did I mistake something? Any help is appreciated!

Terminology nit-pick: One says "square summable", not "twice summable"

@MPW I have modified.

I figure it out: $H_0$ is not closed, so the Riesz representation theorem for $H_0$ does not work.

Indeed, the post I linked to showed you that your initial "by Fatou's lemma it's easy to see that $H_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^2$" was wrong.
